# File V/S in-memory storage of network data

Tags: c++

We have a scenario where a certain function is called a lot of times in code. The function downloads the same URL over the network.

The way I implemented this is :

Download the network data -> save it to file -> read the file and process as needed

In subsequent function calls, this function first checks if the data is already downloaded and the file already exists and if true, just reads the file.

This is done so that we don't download the same network data again and again.

However, in code review, other engineers insist that using local static variables to store this network data is a good idea rather than using the file system - can someone explain why? Why are local static variables preferred over the file system approach?

Please note that the network data is really small - size of storage is not a constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Well, storing a file in the File system is bound to take more time then storing it in the memory ([See Wikipedia entry on Memory Hierarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_hierarchy)). The essential question here is persistance: is it necessary to persist the (notably small amount of data) over several program starts? If not you should probably keep it in memory (possibly even in an already processed state for quick access).

Another point: reading and writing files can go wrong (just look at all the possible exceptions in the MSDN entries of these classes). If you don't win anything by writing data to the file system, then don't do it (as it just adds another potential hazard to your code),